# Load data in DropdownList by category wise

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

in my ASP.net web application i want load in dropdownlist box by category wise like below screenshot.. How can i do it??
I gonna use two table in DB
One is to Store Available Course
Second Table is Number of Degree like below

[image]

Comment: You can do it with optgroup in select html tag for showing like above, For storing category you can do it in single table by child parent relation.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify using optGroup in dropdown...

please follow below link it might be useful for resolve your problem..

[Group options for Asp.Net DropDownList](http://mpurna.blogspot.in/2012/01/group-options-for-aspnet-dropdownlist.html)

Enjoy coding....